# What is the equivalent of Expanded widget of Flutter in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I am pretty much new to `Jetpack Compose` and I want to create a simple business card app like this:

[image]

The way I want to achieve this layout is to create two main `Columns`, one for the upper part (logo with name and title) and one for the lower part of the screen (contact details). I want the first `Column` to take all the remaining space of the screen, so the lower `Column` goes to the end of the page. In `Flutter` I would place both of the `Columns` in a parent `Column` and wrap the first `Column` with `Expanded`, and it would do the job. So how to achieve the same behavior in `Jetpack Compose`? The code is as follows:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BusinessCardTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    BusinessCard()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LogoNameTitle() {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.android_logo),
            contentDescription = "",
        )
        Text("Jennifer Doe", color = Color.White)
        Text("Android Developer Extraordinaire", color = Color.Green)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ContactInformation() {
    Column() {
        Row() {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Phone, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Green)
            Text("+11 (123) 444 555 666", color = Color.White)
        }
        Row() {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Share, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Green)
            Text("@AndroidDev", color = Color.White)
        }
        Row() {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Email, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Green)
            Text("jen.doe@android.com", color = Color.White)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BusinessCard() {
    Surface(color = Color.DarkGray) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            LogoNameTitle()
            ContactInformation()
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun BusinessCardPreview() {
    BusinessCardTheme {
        BusinessCard()
    }
}
```

And the current output is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as parent container a `Column` and just apply the **`weight(1f)`** modifier to the 1st nested `Column` (name and title).

Something like:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
   
   Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().weight(1f)){
        //Logo and title    
   }
   Column(){
       //Contact info
        Text("First Name")
        Text("Surname")
        Text("Other info")
   }
}
```

[image]

Pls note that the `weight` modifier requires a `ColumnScope`. In your case use the modifier as parameter:

```
@Composable
fun LogoNameTitle(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        //...
    }
}

@Composable
fun BusinessCard() {
    Surface(color = Color.DarkGray,modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            LogoNameTitle(modifier=Modifier.weight(1f))
            ContactInformation()
        }
    }
}
```